How to move away from CustomHttpClientFactory in Flurl 4.0?
What we have implemented currently is something like this: https://v3.flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#httpclientfactory with the CustomHttpClientFactory being a  BearerTokenManagingHttpClientFactory which inherits DefaultHttpClientFactory and overrides CreateHttpClient() and CreateMessageHandler() methods. It adds some headers in the override of CreateHttpClient and returns something called BearerTokenMessageHandler object in the override of CreateMessageHandler. BearerTokenMessageHandler itself inherits DelegatingHandler.
Now, I did got through the upgrade guide, but I'm having difficulty in migrating from 3.x to 4.0 especially. I want to understand what's the 4.0 equivalent code for
var cli = new FlurlClient(BASE_URL).Configure(settings => {
    settings.HttpClientFactory = new MyCustomHttpClientFactory();
});


Factories are gone in 4.0. Everything you want to do is covered here.

Hi @ToddMenier, I did go through that documentation, but the places I'm having difficulty is the dots(...) in the documentation. As a complete novice developer, referring the documentation I'm unable to achieve what I want to achieve. Especially, mentioning IFlurlClientBuilder in the text and using IFlurlClientCache in the example doesn't help either. Is IFlurlClientCache similar to IFlurlClientBuilder? (Asking this because builder is not mentioned in IFlurlClientCache). A bit more explanation about caching client vs non-caching client would help me in understanding further about the concept.

This answer might help you. You are correct that you need an IFlurlClientBuilder to mess with message handlers. And if you're not using the cache/DI nor the clientless pattern, you can just new up a FlurlClientBuilder directly as described in that answer.
